# Remove all lines does not contain in other file

Tags: regex, emeditor

I have file A 'Emails' with so many email , and file B 'Domain' with so many domain

Example File A 'Emails ':

```
ctv@ymail.com
kfi@aol.in
hi@axus.cc
0@gmail.com
igp@yahoo.com
encor@mail2.com
cjang@mail.com
vn@gmail.com
87@gmail.com
ee@maoyt.com
```

Example file B 'Domain'

```
@gmail.com
@yahoo.com
```

My expected result :

```
0@gmail.com
igp@yahoo.com
vn@gmail.com
87@gmail.com
```

is there a way to do with 2 file in `emeditor` .Thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose using the Join CSV function. @Abimanyu's regex method may work if you have less than 10 or so domains. More than that, it might take a while to process the data.

To prepare the document for joining, right click on the CSV/Sort toolbar and edit the User-defined separated format to use `@` as the delimiter.

[image: Customize window]

Now on both file A and file B, change the CSV mode to User-defined separated. On the CSV/Sort toolbar, there is a button called "Join CSV".

[image: Join CSV window]

Join CSV options:

- Make sure the correct documents are selected
- Key Column is the email domain columns
- In the list at the bottom, select the output columns, which should be column 1 and 2 from file A

Press the Join Now button, change CSV mode to Normal mode and you will get an output which looks like this:

```
0@gmail.com
igp@yahoo.com
vn@gmail.com
87@gmail.com
```

Comment: Thanks ,this solution work well ,but can i use this way to find duplicated and not duplicated between 2 files in EmEditor ?

Comment: @LeNguyen I don't understand the question, about finding "duplicates between 2 files". Duplicates of email domains? Duplicates in the join output?

Comment: i mean ,find the duplicated lines between 2 file ,examle File A and File B , filter duplicated lines ,filter lines in A but not in B ,filter Lines in B but not in A

Comment: i know compare function in EmEditor ,but it does not export result

Comment: @LeNguyen That is what "Include all non-matching rows" checkbox in Join CSV window is for.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will be help to you  :

Pattern : `.*@gmail.com|.*@yahoo.com`

```
Match groups:
Match 1
1.  0@gmail.com
Match 2
1.  igp@yahoo.com
Match 3
1.  vn@gmail.com
Match 4
1.  87@gmail.com
```

https://rubular.com/r/M3MVSoRj6qnSbl

Comment: And how do you create this pattern from `file B`? What happens if `file B` contains hundreds of domains?

Comment: Thanks ,but this way seems to be complex because 'file B' contain alot alot alot of lines ,this solution could do for limited lines